# Tikz pgf loglog y-axis and log x-axis for use as Weibull probability network (german: "Weibullwahrscheinlichkeitspapier")

Tags: tikz-pgf, axis

I am trying to implement a Weibull probability network (german: "Weibullwahrscheinlichkeitspapier") with tikz-pgf.

**Please take a closer look at the left y-axis: it is not log, it is double log! I want to reproduce this y-axis and the double log grid.**

[image: Weibull probability network]

The linearly scaled y-axis is shown on the right as secondary y-axis.

The problem is that the left y-axis is scaled twice logarithmically, that is, the definition of the **left** y-axis is:

[image: equation loglog y-axis]

---

**Here is what I want to achieve:**

[image: comparison single log and double log y-axis]

---

*Here is a table of the values of y*

[image: Table of the values of y:]

---

I started here:

**Code**

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        height = 10cm,
        width = 15cm,
        grid=both,
        xmode=log, ymode=log,
        xmin=1e0, xmax=1e4,
        ymin=1e-2, ymax=1,
        ]

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: x-y-grid]

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have considered the update in your question and now I understood what you want. I hope that this is the desired result.

1. With `y coord trafo` you can treat you y-axis values as you want. I put inside the `ln` a constant `1e-4` in order to avoid problems when pgfplots tries to calculate `ln 0`.
2. The values calculated in the second axis (the right one) comes from the following equation. Substitute the y-values of -2, -1.5, and so on to get the probabilities Pa.

[image: Example]

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{set layers}
\begin{axis}[
/pgfplots/y coord trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{log10(abs(ln(1.-#1+1e-4)))},
scale only axis,
axis y line*=left,
height = 10cm,
width = 15cm,
grid=both,
xmode=log,
xmin=1e0, xmax=1e4,
ymin=1e-2,ymax=1e0,
ytick={1e-2,3e-2,5e-2,1e-1,3e-1,4e-1,6.3212055883e-1,8e-1,9e-1,9.9e-1,9.99e-1,1e0},
yticklabels={0.01,0.03,0.05,0.1,0.3,0.4,0.63,0.8,0.9,0.99,0.999,1},
xlabel=$t\,(\log)$,
ylabel=$P_\mathrm{A}$,
]
\end{axis}%
\begin{axis}[
/pgfplots/y coord trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{log10(abs(ln(1.-#1+1e-4)))},
scale only axis,
axis y line*=right,
axis x line=none,
height = 10cm,
width = 15cm,
grid=both,
xmode=log,
xmin=1e0, xmax=1e4,
ymin=1e-2,ymax=1e0,
ytick={1e-2,0.03112800566,1e-1,0.27110658589,0.63212055883,0.95767078038,1e0},
yticklabels={-2,-1.5,-1,-0.5,0,0.5,1},
ylabel=$\log\left(-\ln(1-P_\mathrm{A})\right)$,
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

If you want it with percentages in the left axis, copy the following code.

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{set layers}
\begin{axis}[
/pgfplots/y coord trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{log10(abs(ln(1.-#1+1e-4)))},
scale only axis,
axis y line*=left,
height = 10cm,
width = 15cm,
grid=both,
xmode=log,
xmin=1e0, xmax=1e4,
ymin=1e-2,ymax=1e0,
ytick={1e-2,3e-2,5e-2,1e-1,3e-1,4e-1,6.3212055883e-1,8e-1,9e-1,9.9e-1,9.99e-1,1e0},
yticklabels={1.0,3.0,5.0,10.0,30.0,40.0,63.2,80.0,90.0,99.0,99.9,100.0},
xlabel=$t\,(\log)$,
ylabel=$P_\mathrm{A}\,(\%)$,
]
\end{axis}%
\begin{axis}[
/pgfplots/y coord trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{log10(abs(ln(1.-#1+1e-4)))},
scale only axis,
axis y line*=right,
axis x line=none,
height = 10cm,
width = 15cm,
grid=both,
xmode=log,
xmin=1e0, xmax=1e4,
ymin=1e-2,ymax=1e0,
ytick={1e-2,0.03112800566,1e-1,0.27110658589,0.63212055883,0.95767078038,1e0},
yticklabels={-2,-1.5,-1,-0.5,0,0.5,1},
ylabel=$\log\left(-\ln(1-P_\mathrm{A})\right)$,
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: unfortunately, this is not exactly what I want. I need the left y-axis to be scaled double log according to the equation I mentioned in my question. But thank you anyway :)

Comment: I can update my answer but I don't understand at all what you want. What do you mean by scaled double log? Could you please add an image or something in order to clarify what you want? Have a nice day.

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts, Sebastián! I have added a new image that shows the scaling of the y-axis I want to achieve. Do you understand now?

Comment: I've just edited my answer! Hope you like it :D `@user3116388`

Comment: Thank you! This is it! :)